# The argument type 'Iterable>' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'List'

Tags: list, flutter, dart, group-by

I trying to groupBy a list by below code

```
var b = groupBy(value[index],(ABC item) => item.id);
dropDownMenuItem = buildDropDownMenuItems(b.values);
```

The b now is `Map<String, List<ABC>>`

In `buildDropDownMenuItems`, I want pass the `List<ABC>`

```
List<DropdownMenuItem<ABC>> buildDropDownMenuItems(List<ABC> asset) {
  ......
  }
```

Error

> The argument type 'Iterable>' can't be assigned to the
>   parameter type 'List'.

Comment: Can you add full console log too?

Comment: @CrazyLazyCat No log in console, just a red line under `buildDropDownMenuItems(b.values);`.

Comment: ok make it as `buildDropDownMenuItems(b.values.toList());`

Comment: @CrazyLazyCat `The argument type 'List<List<ABC>>' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'List<ABC>'.dart(argument_type_not_assignable)`

Comment: you are confusing with `Map<key, value>().values`. I thing you have to do something like this `buildDropDownMenuItems(b["Group Name"]);`

Comment: @CrazyLazyCat thanks. It works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `expand` function on your `values`

```
var b = groupBy(value[index],(ABC item) => item.id);
dropDownMenuItem = buildDropDownMenuItems(b.values.expand((item) => item).toList());
```

but obviously it gives you same ungrouped list before `group by` function. Probably you wanted to use it as `b["your key"]`

```
var b = groupBy(value[index],(ABC item) => item.id);
dropDownMenuItem = buildDropDownMenuItems(b["your key"]);
```